# How does replacing CoC accounts on multiple devices work?

Tags: clash-of-clans, ios

If I have two CoC accounts, three different devices and wanted to replace one of them with the other, would all of them be replaced? I would like to replace one of the villages with the other as I no longer have access to the third iOS device.

If I log into the Game Center account for my third device on the second device, it says something along the lines of "would you like to replace ...village with... village? Doing so will delete all progress". If I do this will I lose the progress on my first device?

Answer (score 2):

**Answering this question will assume that the 1st and the 2nd device share the same coc account.**

We assume that the 1st and 2nd device share coc account named "no1", and the 3rd device's coc account named "no2"

The answer is **NO** , because **as long as the 1st device still uses the account "no1"**, if you delete "no1" in the 2nd device, it just log out the account "no1" from the 2nd device, and not deleting the whole account.

**But remember, this method only works when the 1st device still holds the account "no1", or else it won't work!**

Answer (score 0):

Probably not because it's only talking about the device you are transferring it to.

Answer (score 0):

Unless that is not connected to a separate Game Center profile, no it would not. Even though it reads you that message it will still be saved and accessible on the Game Center profile. I have done this multiple times and have multiple accounts running on one device.